# Client side markdown display is struggling with newlines

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

Just seen this:

[image]

No amount of adding or removing whitespace or text around that point fixed the preview. (The server side rendering worked.)

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649341/67392).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the markdown rendering, it is a bug in the post text.

The post contains a `</pre>` too much, which breaks the preview.

```
<pre>

^\d+(\.\d+)+$
    ^\d+(\.\d+)+$
</pre>


should work.
</pre>
```

With a little luck, the actual post doesn't show the missing line break, but the actual problem is the `pre`.

I updated the post and it shows fine now.

Comment: After a while all those tags just blend in to each other :-)

Comment: Indeed. I always wonder why people use `pre` while you have markdown...

Comment: For me often because the normal code markup will apply syntax highlighting (and, as in the case, remembering the right magic to switch it off would take longer than adding the tags).

Comment: @Richard that might be true. Then we should fix that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I use `pre` for code blocks following a list (in cases where the rendering is otherwise broken).

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess you mean that you need 8 spaces for code blocks instead of 4?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I wasn't thing of that one (but your right). I don't need it very often, from memory it's when the code block contains html? or at least `<` characters? Anyway some character of other does not display in the code block.